# PyQgis won't find dockwidget child

Tags: pyqgis

Manually in the PythonConsole I can open or close panels but when is executed in code it won't find the dockwidget, this is the line I'm using in my code:

`self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'PythonConsole').setVisible(True)`

and this one works in the PythonConsole:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'PythonConsole').setVisible(True)
```

it is supposed to work but give the error "NoneType" object has no attribute "setVisible" when executed in the code...

Comment: When is your plugin calling this line? If it's on plugin load, it may be trying to hide the console BEFORE it's been created.

Comment: it waits for the a layer to load for first time, once the layer is loaded it calls the line   `self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget,'PythonConsole').setVisible(True)`

Comment: Does it work if you show and then hide the console manually first?

Comment: @ndawson yes it does... but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is created "on demand", so doesn't exist until a user first clicks the console button.

An alternative way to show the dock is to use:

```
import console
console.show_console()
```

This will force creation of the console dock if it hasn't yet been used. Caution: despite it's name, show_console() is more of a "toggle console" action. Calling it when the console is already visible will hide it.